# XSL-FO Overflow Handling for fo:inline-container Elements

Tags: xslt, stylesheet, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

### XSL-FO Overflow Handling for fo:inline-container Elements

My question is: How is it possible to break contents (e.g. **fo:block** elements) inside a **fo:inline-container** to a new page if the iherit contents are too long for the current one?

Used Fomatters: AHF 6.2, Apache FOP 2.1

- The transformation has to work for both formatters; so a simple solution with fo:float elements is not possible.

Here is a short code extract:

```
<xsl:template match="myElement">
    <fo:block>
        <fo:inline-container inline-progression-dimension="33.333%">
            <fo:block>
                Marginalia Headline
            </fo:block>
        </fo:inline-container>

        <fo:inline-container inline-progression-dimension="66.666%">
            <fo:block>
                Imagine this is a very long text ...
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block>
                Imagine this is a very long text ...
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block>
                Imagine this is a very long text ...
            </fo:block>
            <!-- MANY MORE fo:blocks -->
        </fo:inline-container>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

The thing is, the contents are overflowing the fo:inline-container but are not breaking onto a new page. I think this has something to do with the **surrounding fo:block** element that keeps everything on a single page.

Any advice would be helpful here. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which formatter are you using?  Have you tried using, e.g., side floats or `fo:list-block` for this?

Comment: I am using both, the AntennaHouse formatter 6.2 and Apache FOP. So for Antenna House the fo:float method would fit. But for FOP it would not. The thing is that the surrounding fo:block, in combination with the fo:inline-container elements, keeps everything on a single page. I´d rather not place my contents in a table and also not in a list-block.

Comment: AFAIK, FOP can only do side floats, and floating to top, bottom, column, etc., isn't required for this anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## What works

### Using fo:list-block

*(Ok, you said you'd rather not use this trick ... anyway this works and could be used as a last resort)*

You can put the marginalia in the `fo:list-item-label` and the "normal" text in the `fo:list-item-body`:

```
        <fo:list-block provisional-distance-between-starts="33.333%">
            <fo:list-item>
                <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
                    <fo:block>
                        Marginalia Headline
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:list-item-label>
                <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
                    <fo:block>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor ...
                    </fo:block>
                    <!-- other blocks ... -->
                </fo:list-item-body>
            </fo:list-item>
        </fo:list-block>
```

### Using overflowing fo:block-container

Alternatively, you could use a flatter sequence of formatting objects, putting the marginalia into a **zero-height block container**, so that the following block of normal text will start at the same height:

```
        <fo:block-container height="0pt" overflow="visible" keep-with-next.within-page="always">
            <fo:block end-indent="66.666%">
                Marginalia Headline
            </fo:block>
        </fo:block-container>
        <fo:block start-indent="33.333%">
            Lorem ipsum dolor ...
        </fo:block>
        <!-- other blocks ... -->
```

Note that this solution can lead to a marginalia overflowing into the page bottom margin or overlapping the next marginalia if it produces more than X lines, where X is the `orphans` property of its corresponding normal text (for example, marginalia is three lines long while the normal text has `orphans="2"`).

## What does not work

### Using fo:float

Even if FOP supports side-floats, I don't think using them would achieve the desired output, as the text would flow around it, returning to use all the available horizontal space as soon as possible:

```
        <fo:block>
            <fo:float float="left">
                <fo:block width="33.333%" background-color="#AAFFFF">Marginalia Headline</fo:block>
            </fo:float>
            <fo:block background-color="#FFAAFF">
                Lorem ipsum dolor ...
            </fo:block>
            <!-- other blocks ... -->
        </fo:block>
```

[image: output using floats]

### Using fo:inline-container

I think the code in the question does not work as expected not because of something missing in the outer `fo:block`, but because of something missing in the `fo:inline-container` containing the long text: the `overflow` attribute.

If unspecified, its default value is `"auto"` which means the formatting object processor can do as it likes (probably showing the content even if overflows). With `overflow="repeat"` the processor should, if needed, create other areas, so that the content will be split into pages:

```
        <fo:block>
            <fo:inline-container inline-progression-dimension="33.333%">
                <fo:block>
                    Marginalia Headline
                </fo:block>
            </fo:inline-container><fo:inline-container inline-progression-dimension="66.666%" overflow="repeat">
                <fo:block>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor ...
                </fo:block>
                <!-- other blocks ... -->
            </fo:inline-container>
        </fo:block>
```

FOP, however, does **not** support `overflow="repeat"` (I cannot test with Antenna House XslFormatter, but the [conformance page](https://www.antennahouse.com/xslfo/axf4fo.htm#IDAFXRQ) says it is supported).

*(Disclosure: I am an inactive FOP developer)*

Comment: OK. So I´ll stick with the <fo:list> hack. Because it works for both processors and gives a 1:1 PDF output. However I tried to use fo:floats and they kind of work. I say "kind of" because the layout didn´t look the same in FOP as it did in AHF. Thank you and the other guys for your competent help! This helped a lot.